# Sum integers on AIX using parameters

Tags: bash, shell, aix

Today I have a script that inside of it has a query that does a SELECT of the column name and the count of it. It can list more than 50+ different lines.

Ex.

```
BOOK 12
SHELF 2
DESK 3
```

Outline code:

```
[query] | while read unk_mtype_volume ; do

    echo "$unk_mtype_volume"

done
```

I need to SUM every row number, to have a total.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple job for `awk`, no expensive iteration over the lines of the file/input needed. Just add up the second fields, and finally print the value:

```
awk '{sum+=$2} END{print sum}' file.txt
```

If the input is coming from STDIN:

```
... | awk '{sum+=$2} END{print sum}'
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
BOOK 12
SHELF 2
DESK 3

% awk '{sum+=$2} END{print sum}' file.txt
17
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (and I would) use `awk` for the job — as shown by [heemayl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3789550/heemayl) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41938470/15168).  You can also do it in pure Bash:

```
sum=0
while read location number
do
    sum=$(($sum + $number))
done
echo "Total: $sum"
```

Note that this is fragile if any of the 'locations' consists of more than one word.  You can code around that more easily in `awk` than Bash.